# How to get the accuracy of predicted model python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I made model from `sklearn` for multiclass text classification

I want to know the accuracy of predicted sentence I give to model

```
level0_model.predict(['I sold 4 apples for 4 Dollar'])
```

> Output : sell

I want something like that

> Output : sell accuracy : %99

Comment: For getting accuracy, you will need the ground truth label. If you have that, you can use [accuracy_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html) to compute accuracy. If you can provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I can help with a working example

Comment: @miladjurablu accuracy tells you how well your model performs, i.e. the percentage of correctly predicted samples. You cannot get 99% accuracy on a single prediction, as in your example. You can get either 0% (wrong prediction) or 100% (right prediction). If you want to see how confident your model is about its prediction use `model.predict_proba()`. If you need something else you should improve your question

Answer (score 1):

From the example you have given, I am assuming you are looking for the **prediction probability/confidence**, not the actual **accuracy** (which is used for performance evaluation).

I am not sure which model exactly you are using, but sklearn models offer a `predict_proba()` method, returning the estimated probabilities.
See [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/search.html?q=predict_proba) for a list of all models with such a method in sklearn.